# On the Community Events entry page, the duration text box doesn't show its value

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, community-events

On the moderator-only Create/Edit page for Community Events (`/admin/community-events`), the text box that contains the number of days or hours ahead of time in which to show the event displays as empty, despite the fact that there's apparently a value in there.

If I create the event without attempting to modify the value, the event is created using the default value of 7. I can't tell with reliability what happens when I try to type into that box, but it's not helpful.

[image: "Create a new event" page with empty-looking text-box circled]

I have seen this issue on Mi Yodeya, on a Windows 7 computer, using Chrome Version 70 and using Internet Explorer 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

The text area had a width of 20px, which should be sufficient for two digits.  Unfortunately, there was 10px of padding on either side, giving us zero space for text.  Either there used to be less padding or we used to be using a different box model where width was measured inside padding.  I've bumped up the allotted space the text fits again.